# PHP MySQL insert statement won't insert data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem inserting a string into a MySQL table. My code is:

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO jos_content (
    title, alias, introtext, metakey, state, created_by, metadesc)
VALUES ('$izv','$izv','$forprint','$mk',1,62,'$izv')" );
```

Everything works as expected when the variable `$forprint` isn't in the query, but when I add it the query my database doesn't update. `$forprint` is a string longer than 4000 chars.

EDIT:

with mysql_real_escape_string input was passed to db, but with some missing.

The part which is missing is:

```
<p><br></p><table style="text-align: left;" mce_style="text-align: left;" 
class="mceItemTable" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td colspan="2" 
rowspan="1"><h1 style="text-align: center;">HP</h1></br></br><h1 style="text-
align: center;" mce_style="text-align: center;"><br><p><br></p><p></h1></p><p><a 
href="#" mce_href="#" onclick="jwplayer().load('/templates/BV/list
/HP.xml')"><p style="text-align: center;" mce_style="text-align: 
center;">SDS</p></a><br mce_bogus="1"></p><br mce_bogus="1"></td></tr>
```

so in my exit.txt which is generated from $forprint all data is there, but in DB this part, and closing part of table is missing.

EDIT2:
PDO did the job, thank you for advices.

Comment: How does that table look like? I mean the column types...

Comment: Where is that variable set? What does it contain? Have you escaped it so no apostrophes etc are in it?Also try to use PDO not mysql functions, they are deprecated (no longer supported)

Comment: You need to debug the error. Since it is a long string, my bet is on characters which break the SQL.  `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: What is introtext datatype? use `Text` datatype for introtext

Comment: Depending on where your variables come from, this may be subject to injection attacks. Also, the value in `$forprint` may be creating an illegal SQL statement. You should use parameter binding.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 5):

What is the contents of `$forprint`? Does it contain `'`? If so, that will cause problems. Do the contents of `$forprint` come from the user? If so you have **serious** problems.

### You're not escaping your variables which could be extremly dangerous by allowing for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Try using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

For example:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


mysql_select_db("balkan", $con);

$izv_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($izv,$con);
$mk_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($mk,$con);
$forprint_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($forprint,$con);

$query = <<<END_OF_SQL
  INSERT INTO jos_content (title, alias, introtext, metakey, state, created_by, metadesc)
  VALUES ('$izv_safe','$izv_safe','$forprint_safe','$mk_safe',1,62,'$izv_safe')"
END_OF_SQL;

mysql_query($query,$con);
```

Better yet, use [prepared statements via mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: +1 for `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: i dont need safe solution because this script wont be online on website so i didnt put it.

content of forprint have many of '

Comment: You always need `mysql_real_escape_string`. If there's a `'` in the string, you need to escape the string.

Comment: didnt know that tbh. i updated my post with new problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the length for `varchar` type for column `introtext`, and make it 4000+ chars `say varchar(6000)`

Comment: its not varchar is mediumtext

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there is a single quote and It's breaking the insert query.

You must escape quotes on a string.

Something like,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jos_content 
            (title, alias, introtext, metakey, state, created_by, metadesc)
            VALUES (
              '".mysql_real_escape_string($izv)."',
              '".mysql_real_escape_string($izv)."',
              '".mysql_real_escape_string($forprint)."',
              '".mysql_real_escape_string($mk)."',
              1,
              62 ,
              '".mysql_real_escape_string($izv)."'
            )
");
```

Of course you should do the same thing for all text inputs.

Comment: this did work but not completely.  some text is missing

Comment: Did you use it for all text inputs? look at my updated answer again.

Comment: yes i did, i updated my first post with new problem and missing stuff